# Custom JS encryption algorithm over http?

Tags: javascript, http, encryption

I know that most secure way of transmitting data between client and server is HTTPS but I've been wondering, would encrypting user input before sending it to server (AJAX) work? And then server to process it accordingly... I see no way, even if someone sniffs that encrypted data to decrypt it, like for example Enigma encryption method they used, even though it was decrypted, methods can always change.

So would this work and what would the concerns be?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [Cryptography - why shouldn't we roll our own?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

Comment: yeah, you can use any sort of private-key encryption and many forms of public-key on top of http(s). this includes most ciphers. the problem is getting the client and server on the same key without sending it over the net.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that HTTPS actually serves more than one purpose.  In addition to encryption, there is also verification that the server (and client in some cases) you think you are talking to is actually that client you think you are talking to.  You should use HTTPS for anything that needs to be secure.

Now, if for academic reasons or a specific use case you want to use encryption with JavaScript, yes this is entirely possible.  I recommend an asymmetric algorithm, like RSA.  There are JavaScript implementations of it.  The key for encrypting is different than the key for decrypting.  Because of this, even if the encryption key is known (and if someone is packet sniffing, it will be), eavesdroppers won't be able to decrypt the data.

Here's a JavaScript implementation I've used before for this purpose:  http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/

Just remember... the chances of making a mistake are high.  By using HTTPS, you are using heavily tested implementations by security experts, and you don't have to reinvent the wheel.  Use what is already there if at all possible.

Comment: if only SSL ECHO had been extensively tested...  ;-)

Comment: I've more had in mind like plain encryption without a key, if you understand what I mean. I send for example string 'SK0XO2D'... with server having a decryption method turning that to 'Hello'...

Comment: @user2818626 All useful encryption uses a key of some sort.